# Modifying Windows Frame in Python (The professional way?)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have been using pyqt and qt designer to make a program.  I wanted to custom style the top bar which holds the icon and minimize,resize,close buttons.  To do this I started with using the Qt.FramelessWindowHint and making custom buttons and such.  This has led to many problems with grabbing corners to resize and also snapping (all the built in windows functions).  I was trying to sort through this but found many people talking about the problems that I am having. I was trying to go for the google chrome/maya/photoshop look where the top part is completely customized.  A friend pointed out that if any of these programs crash, you can notice the windows bar will show through, which means they are not actually removing it but styling above it or something of that sort.  How can I go about doing this so all the functionality is still there but it is styled.